# str_replace in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, str-replace

```
<?php 

$url = "http://localhost/news&lang=en&lang=sk&lang=sk&lang=sk&lang=en";

$langs = array ('sk', 'en');

foreach ($langs as $lang) {
    $search = '&lang='.$lang;    
    $new = str_replace($search, "", $url);
}

echo $new; // output: http://localhost/news

?>
```

Q: How to delete all parameters (&lang=en, &lang=sk) from string ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are looking for [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/parse_url), possibly with [`http_build_url`](http://www.php.net/http_build_url), or it's PHP-code equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is creating a new variable `$new` each time so that won't do anything good with the `$url`.
Try to assign the `str_replace` back to its original variable like:

```
$url = "http://localhost/news&lang=en&lang=sk&lang=sk&lang=sk&lang=en";

$langs = array ('sk', 'en');

foreach ($langs as $lang) {
    $search = '&lang='.$lang;    
    $url = str_replace($search, "", $url);
}

echo $url; // output: http://localhost/news
```

Answer (score 0):

An Alternative:

First:

```
$url = "http://localhost/news&lang=en&lang=sk&lang=sk&lang=sk&lang=en";
echo preg_replace("#&lang=(en|sk)#", "", $url);
```

Second:

```
$url = "http://localhost/news&lang=en&lang=sk&lang=sk&lang=sk&lang=en";
echo str_replace(array("&lang=en", "&lang=sk"), "", $url);
```

**Update: for long array of $lang:**

```
$url = "http://localhost/news&lang=en&lang=sk&lang=sk&lang=sk&lang=en";
echo preg_replace("#&lang=(".implode("|", $lang).")#", "", $url);
```

Comment: array `$langs` can contain more values

Answer (score 0):

You want to use parse_url() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php and then http_build_query() http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php